# How to crate replica in solr and what are the method to create

Tags: solr

I have a question regarding Solr replica how to create and what is the different way to create in solr and please explain and elaborate to simple way so I can understand because I am new to solr .

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/replica-management.html#addreplica ?

Answer (score 0):

Replicas are exact copies of your shards and this will actually provide redundancy. To achieve high-availability/fault-tolerant behavior, every node of the cluster must have a replica of every collection.

When you [create a collection](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/collection-management.html#create-parameters), using the `replicationFactor` parameter you can specify the number of replicas to be created for each shard.

Example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collectionName&numShards=number&replicationFactor=number
```

Here is an example command to [add a replica](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/replica-management.html#addreplica):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection=collectionName&shard=shard1&node=localhost:8983_solr
```

In the Solr documentation, you can find the `ADDREPLICA parameters` to use,  for example the **type** parameter. In fact, there are 3 types of replicas; the default is NRT(Near real time) replicas, eligible to become the leader and are the only ones supporting soft commits.

Also, Solr provides a way to [automatically add replicas](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/solrcloud-autoscaling-auto-add-replicas.html) for a collection when the number of active replicas drops below the replication factor specified at the time of the creation of the collection.
**N.B.** The autoscaling framework in its current form is deprecated and will be removed in Solr 9.0.

Depending on the version of Solr you are using, [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/) you can find the relative reference guide.